How to load json into postgres?
I'm trying to create a table in the Postgres database where json will be sent using the API. There are many hundreds of store clients in the json file. Sometimes the file may contain part of the client’s data, sometimes complete data. I want to implement the logic - client recognition. For example, data is sent for one person:

Michael, +445000123456
Smith, smith@test.com
05/25/1975, smith@test.com
smith@test.com, +445000123456
4654891321435, smith@test.com (GoogleID)
4654891321435, 846546 (Google ID and Telegram ID chat)

And I want to get unified
Michael, +445000123456, 05/25/1975, smith@test.com, 4654891321435
This is done because client data can come from a website, CRM, etc..
As a result, if there is no record, then we create a new one, otherwise we update the record in the postgres table, adhering to the search priority (Phone, mail, Google ID, Telegram ID chat).
There is also logic: if the field is null, then we skip updating this field; if there is an empty "", then we erase the field; if there is a value, then we update the field (not the entire line).
-- Create the database if it does not exist
SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE mydbtest ENCODING ''UTF8'''
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydbtest')\gexec;

-- Connect to the mydbtest database
\c mydbtest

-- Create a schema if it doesn't exist
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mydbtest;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydbtest.customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'),
    googleID VARCHAR(50),
    externalID VARCHAR(50),
    firstName VARCHAR(100),
    lastName VARCHAR(100),
    birthday DATE,
    phoneNumber BIGINT,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    telegramChatId BIGINT,
    registrAt TIMESTAMP,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP,
    updateAt TIMESTAMP,
    defaultAddress JSONB,
    customFields JSONB,
    tags TEXT[],
    api JSONB,
    is_deleted BOOLEAN
);

-- Create a function to check uniqueness
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mydbtest.check_unique_contact()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mydbtest.customers
        WHERE (COALESCE(NEW.phoneNumber::text, NEW.email, NEW.telegramChatId::text, NEW.googleID) IS NOT NULL)
          AND (COALESCE(NEW.phoneNumber::text, NEW.email, NEW.telegramChatId::text, NEW.googleID) =
               COALESCE(phoneNumber::text, email, telegramChatId::text, googleID))
          AND id != NEW.id
    ) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Duplicate contact information';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create a trigger to check uniqueness
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_unique_contact
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mydbtest.customers
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION mydbtest.check_unique_contact();

-- Create indexes for fields that are often used in searches
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_phoneNumber ON mydbtest.customers (phoneNumber);
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_email ON mydbtest.customers (email);
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_telegramChatId ON mydbtest.customers (telegramChatId);
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_googleID ON mydbtest.customers (googleID);

-- Create an index for full-text search by first and last name
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_name ON mydbtest.customers (firstName, lastName);

-- Create an index to search by date of birth
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_birthday ON mydbtest.customers (birthday);

-- Create an index to search by creation date
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_createdAt ON mydbtest.customers (createdAt);

-- Create an index for searching by tags
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_tags ON mydbtest.customers USING GIN (tags);

-- Create an index for JSON fields
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_defaultAddress ON mydbtest.customers USING GIN (defaultAddress);
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_customFields ON mydbtest.customers USING GIN (customFields);
CREATE INDEX idx_customers_api ON mydbtest.customers USING GIN (api);

I would like to try this, but I have two problems:

I don’t know if I did the code below correctly
How to load json via PHP if the file may contain a different order of keys or some of the keys may be missing?

For example,
[{
  "googleID": "4648561651651",
  "externalID": "1",
  "firstName": "Michael",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "birthday": "1975-11-05",
  "gender": "2",
  "phoneNumber": 445000123456,
  "email": "smith@test.com",
  "telegramChatId": "9461111",
  "createdAt": "2022-11-26 12:00:00",
  "registrAt": "2022-11-26 12:00:00",
  "updateAt": "2022-11-26 12:00:00",
  "defaultAddress": {
    "city": "London",
    "full": "1-521"
  },
  "customFields": {
    "vip": "yes"
  },
  "tags": [
    "simple",
    "bloger"
  ],
  "api": {
    "source": "crm",
    "date": "2023-12-26 12:00:00"
  },
  "is_deleted": 0
}]

or so
[{
  "phoneNumber": 445000123456,
  "defaultAddress": {
    "city": "Paris",
  }
}]

then
[{
  "email": "smith@test.com",
  "defaultAddress": {
    "city": "Dubai",
  }
}]

As you can see, in the second file, we must update the city by finding the client by phone number, but if there was no number, then the lower priority is email.
But so far I can’t even load json from PHP, there are always some errors.
$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$fileCustomers = file_get_contents("customers.json");

How to continue and it is advisable not to specify keys (fields); doesn’t Postgres itself know how to sort data into fields according to the key names of the same name?

I don’t know if I did the code below correctly Well, does it work?

I can’t even load json from PHP, there are always some errors Are we supposed to guess what the errors are?

@JohnGordon  There is no need to guess, because there is no point in correcting it if it is not initially clear how to load such json. Here, for example, it’s the same thing, but the clickhouse takes only two lines of code.       $filecustomers = file_get_contents("customers.json");
$clickhouse->query("INSERT INTO org_1719203127.customers FORMAT JSONEachRow $filecustomers"); Is this not possible in Postgres?

That’s not valid SQL. Maybe you should start with that. The manual is very helpful as well, gives you perfectly valid SQL examples

@FrankHeikens What exactly is not valid in SQL?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
